# How to leave static ip?

Tags: ip, modem

I'm trying to leave my ip static, but when I switch from DHCP to IP-Static, my internet does not work images:

[image: image 1]

And:

[image: image 2]

Note: I want to wampserver online, port 80 is already released, but nobody can access, what should I do?

Comment: votedown, please comment!

Comment: Your ISP may not allow you to keep your IP more than a day or so. Use a VPS for reliable web hosting

Comment: Static IP is set by your ISP, you can't get it yourself. Need to contact them and ask for it (probably for an extra fee).

Comment: But with DHCP to leave ip accessible? Leave my site online?

Comment: You're probably getting downvoted because of your lack of research.

Comment: My dear, I researched so much that I came to stop here, my modem has no other dns options, only: dyndns.org

Comment: @Guilherme Then go to dyndns.org and create an account. This will give you a domain name (like www.dyndns.yourname.org). You will assign this to your global IP address (which can be found by going to ipchicken.com). Some modems / routers will automatically update your dyndns account every time your dynamic IP changes. It sounds like yours supports this from what you said so you just provide the modem your dyndns login info and it should behave like a static IP address

Comment: @EricF But it's very expensive, it should have free plans!

Comment: @Guilherme https://www.keycdn.com/blog/best-free-dns-hosting-providers/

Comment: @EricF i have support just this: http://prntscr.com/h7i49m

Comment: My ports is blocked :(

Comment: @Guilherme Then you either pay for Dyndns or you use one of the free ones I listed and update every time your ip changes. Or get a router / modem that supports more for auto updating

Comment: Yes, but, my port is blocked, i want wampserver online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just "use a static IP". You need to have one assigned to you by your ISP, and it usually involves an additional fee.

You may want to look into [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) as an alternative to a Static IP.

Comment: In case, would I have to pay to have an dns?

Comment: You can, but there are free services... the key is "_Dynamic_ DNS", not just DNS.

Comment: Ok I tried configuring, but my modem only has the option dyndns.org

Comment: You don't _have_ to use a DDNS client built into your router... You're running a webserver, so could run the client there instead - just make sure to set the interval appropriately.

Comment: I did not get it until now, I opened the doors, got in touch with the internet provider company and nothing! @Attie

Comment: My ports is blocked :(

Comment: that is very possible